# Using 'grep -e' and more advanced regular expressions

Tags: grep

I'm trying to use the following regular expression in [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) (searches for mixed case [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) files).

```
[A-Z]+[\w.]*\.[pPnNgG]{3}[\\"')]*.*$
```

When I enter the command, my shell displays a `>` looking for more input.

I can use `grep` for some basic regular expressions, but I've never quite gotten the handle of using it with more advanced regular expressions.

FWIW, this is in Cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: Please give more details like example of text you're looking for with grep.

Comment: Do you want to find all png's regardless how they are spelled?

Comment: @Nifle: no, I'd like to find any png's that have at least one capital letter in their path. Our deployment process forces all files to lowercase, so I need to ensure that any references to these files are all lowercase.

Comment: Then you should just find all `.pPnNgG` files regardless how they are spelled/cased and rename them to `$name.png` , renaming a file that are already named `$something.png` wont make a difference.

Comment: @nifle: that actually won't help. I don't want to rename any files (our deployment procedure always uses lower case names) I should have wrote that I want to find any references to these mixed case names inside various code files, so I can ensure that no mixed case names get into our code-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not escape `"` character. Double backslash before will be replaced with single backslash and `"` is left not escaped. Either remove one backslash or add one.

Try this regular expression:

```
grep -i '^[0-9a-z _]\+\.png\([^0-9a-z]+\|$\)' file | grep -v '^[0-9A-Za-z _]\+\.\(png\|PNG\)\([^0-9A-Za-z]\|$\)'
```

It will match all lines containing from the beginning of the line:

- at least on of characters `0-9` (range of `0`, `1`, ..., `9` characters),
  `a-z` `' '` (space), '_'
- a dot (needs to be escaped with backslash, otherwise it will mean 'any single character')
- 'png' (or 'Png', etc. because `-i` is added)
- and not followed by any of `0-9` and
  `a-z` characters (or `A-Z` because `-i` is added).

`-i` - will disable case sensitivity

Comment: Thanks. I actually need the test to be case sensitive (looking for mixed case files in particular). I don't find to match on any png files that are all lowercase.

Comment: Updaded command to exclude files with extension all lowercase or all uppercase. It should display files which have .png mixed case. Also allowed line to end just after file name.